# Managing certificates programmatically in Salesforce Org (after sandbox creation/refresh)

Tags: single-sign-on, automation, saml, sandbox-refresh, certificates

I was trying to find some information on feasibility of creating and deleting self-signed certificates in Salesforce Org programmatically, which could be incorporated into post sandbox creation/refresh script. Steps would include:

– deleting old certificates (usually done manually under Security Controls –> Certificate and Key Management); "Archive Current Key and Create New Key";

– creating self-signed certificate

– editing Single Sign-On Settings –> SAML Single Sign-On Settings

– editing Identity Provider settings

– editing Domain settings

Can you please tell me if anything of mentioned above can be done programmatically in Apex?

Comment: A couple of years ago you couldn't create a certificate programmatically -  [Confirmation that certificates can't be created in unit tests?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49822/confirmation-that-certificates-cant-be-created-in-unit-tests)

Comment: It'd be nice to have an up-to-date answer to this :)